# How to implement basic authentication and authorization in ColdFusion 10 REST APIs?

Tags: api, rest, authentication, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

A few days back I started learning ColdFusion 10 REST APIs. It was very intresting and easy to implement. But now I just want to implement authentication and authorization on my sample APIs. I have searched a lot but not found much useful info on Google.

It may sound like a very basic question, but as I am completly new to REST: Could any one please suggest how to implement authentication on my ColdFusion 10 REST APIs?

My initial thought is to have method named `authenticate()` on my REST enabled cfc, which I will call from all other methods or resources to authenticate the users. I am planning to authenticate the users by their username/password. Is this the correct way to implement?

Answer (score 0):

The way I've seen it in most languages would be to have a base class that takes care of the auth check, usually the presence of a token in the url that matches something against the user in the db for active session.  Then for all of your rest classes, just extend that base class, which is easily done with CFCs in ColdFusion.

Good luck on your implementation!